# IronMQ Unicast Push Queue - do they process serially?

Tags: ironmq

Does an [IronMQ PUSH Queue](http://dev.iron.io/mq/reference/push_queues/) set to unicast wait for a response before pushing the next message?
For example - if I have a unicast queue, and messages A, B, and C come in...will the subscriber consume A - send 200 response, then get sent B - send 200 response, and finally get sent C and send the 200 response....

or will the subscriber get A, B, and C as fast as IronMQ can send them (possibly before the subscriber has a chance to send out any responses...if the processing of the messages takes a few seconds)

Answer (score 3):

IronMQ Push Queues are not serial, it's all in parallel so it does not wait for a response before sending the next message, it will send them out as they come in. There will be a way to set a rate limit in the near future though so you can throttle how fast messages will be pushed.

Update: I just wanted to add that the order that messages are sent to subscribers with "unicast" is random. So if you have a bunch of subscribers, they should get distributed somewhat equally across your subscribers.

Comment: "There will be a way to set a rate limit in the near future though" has this been implemented? I have not seen any documentation on this on the Iron.io site. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Ronburgundy, not yet, but please vote and subscribe to this card to keep up to date: https://trello.com/c/erpq75UE/24-push-queue-throttling